# i want this query in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to know how to write an exact query in laravel using joins, please help somebody to solve this issue

```
select tickets.*  from `employees`  inner join `tickets` on  
 `employees`.`user_id` = `tickets`.`emp_id` inner join  `categories` on  
 `categories`.`acc_id` = `employees`.`acc_id` and `categories`.`id` = 
  (`tickets`.`cat_id` or `tickets`.`cat_id`=0)  where (`employees`.`user_id` = 11)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you using Eloquent or the plain query builder?

Comment: using joins i want this, i have tried like this but not correct
 ->join("categories",function($join){
     $join->on("categories.acc_id","=","employees.acc_id")
     ->on("categories.id","=","tickets.cat_id")
     ->orOn("categories.id","=",DB::raw("0"));

    })

Comment: Please don't post code in comments, you can [edit] your question. Also describe why it's incorrect (in question, not in comments)

Comment: can you try `dd(str_replace_array('?',$laravelWay->getBindings(),$laravelWay->toSql()));`

Comment: it will give you exactly the query that you have posted in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Answer by @Drakula Predator is good

But I avoided using the **Raw** queries

```
$laravelWay = DB::table('employees')
                ->select('tickets.*')
                ->join('tickets','employees.user_id','=','tickets.emp_id')
                ->join('categories', function ($join) {
                        $join->on('categories.acc_id','=','employees.acc_id')
                            ->on('categories.id','=','tickets.cat_id')
                            ->orOn('tickets.cat_id','=','0');
                                })
                ->where('employees.user_id','=',11);
```

Comment: but in @drakula anwer i find this exact  $join->on("categories.id","=",DB::raw("(tickets.cat_id or tickets.cat_id=0)") like this categories.id` = (tickets.cat_id or tickets.cat_id=0)
but not in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using plain query builder,

```
$result = DB::select(DB::raw("tickets.*"))
->join("tickets","employees.user_id","=","tickets.emp_id")
->join('categories', function ($join) {
            $join->on("categories.acc_id","=","employees.acc_id");
            $join->on("categories.id","=",DB::raw("(tickets.cat_id or tickets.cat_id=0)")

})->where("employees.user_id",11)->get();
```

Comment: i will try this

Comment: its coming like this`categories`.`id` = `tickets`.`cat_id` or `tickets`.`cat_id` = `0
but i have shown in my code i want like this 
 `categories`.`id` =   (`tickets`.`cat_id` or `tickets`.`cat_id`=0) in laravel, because i am not getting proper result only this line i want in laravel joins, should be in parenthesis

Comment: if you dont mind i am new for this, how can i accept your answer please help

Comment: click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. See this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpogP.png).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194868/discussion-between-abdul-kaleem-and-drakula-predator).